# "Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada" post request con axios y vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api, axios, cors

Estoy haciendo una petición POST de una API con `axios` desde `vuejs`, cuando consumí esta API desde el servidor me da una respuesta con status code, pero al intentar consumirla desde el componente vue me lanza un error:

> Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en https://... (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito).

Creo que mi problema viene desde el body del post request, ¿cómo puedo configurar este correctamente?

Este es el código (algo robusto):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
     <button v-on:click="fetch">Entrar</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

const username = '...'
const pass = '...'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    methods: {

    fetch() {

      let data= ''
      var token = ''

      axios
           .get('/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=' + username + '&password=' + pass)
           .then(res => {
             console.log(res.data);
             var getToken = JSON.parse(data)
             this.token = getToken.result.token;
             console.log(res);
          }).catch(e => console.log(e.response))

      axios
           .post('/webservice.php', {
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']
             }, body: {
               'operation': 'login',
               'username': username,
               'accessKey': pass,
               'token': token
             }
           })
           .then(response => {console.log(response)
           }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        }
      }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: La API es tuya, es decir la desarrollaste tu?

Answer (score 1):

prueba en tu API PHP a añadir el encabezado CORS:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Cabecera HTTP en PHP para permitir el acceso CORS. (Creo que es el problema)